# RNCamera Usage: how long do temporary photos persist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

When I'm using RNCamera, and not saving the photo to the Camera Roll, what is the persistence of the photo file? If the application crashes, does that photo get deleted eventually or is it saved forever on the device? Do I have to manually find and delete it to manage space correctly? What is the best practice here? Is this handled differently on android and iOS? I can't find any good documentation on this.

Comment: Wondering the same, also how to check the application cache for photos that failed to upload.